# Debugpy (VSCode Python Extension) unable to find 'pydevd_attach_to_process'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

VSCode 1.83.0

Python Extension (Including debugpy) v2023.18.0

Python for Windows: 3.11.6 (using a local venv)

---

I am facing a

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]: 'pydevd_attach_to_process'`

when using the debugger of the official Python extension in VSCode.

Below is my launch.json file.

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Start Dash App",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/folder/app/app.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/folder/app"}
        }
    ]
}
```

The folder `pydevd_attach_to_process` exists within the directory. Do I need to change something on the setup?

When I run the app without the debugger, it works fine.

Python and VSCode have been added to PATH during installation.

Comment: It seems that you are debugging the `app.py`, it is best to show your directory structure and tell us where `app.py` and `pydevd_attach_to_process`are.